# Is there a case aware way to select words?

Tags: key-bindings, words

Is there a way to select words respecting the case... camelCase, snakeCase...

e.g.: i have a word "trullyAwesomeFunction" and cursor is on "w", is there an Emacs function I could use that would select "Awesome" and then if used again select "trully" and then "Function". and deselect them similarly?

Let's say this function bound to `<C-up>` I'm gonna have to press `<C-up>` 3 times to select the entire word. And if it's snake case like: "trully_awesome_function" it would work the similar way.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `subword-mode` (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/MixedCase-Words.html#MixedCase-Words)), a built-in minor mode that makes standard movement and editing commands treat capital letters in camelCaseWords as word boundaries.

For example, you could enable `subword-mode` and then use the standard `mark-word` command (`M-@`) to mark the fragments of "trulyAwesomeFunction" one at a time.

With snake_case, the underscore is already treated as a word boundary by default. In fact there is another minor mode -- `superword-mode` -- that can be enabled if you want the standard word commands to not treat _ as a boundary.

Comment: This is truly awesome.

Comment: Worth noting that `subword-mode` + `mark-word` won't behave *exactly* as described. With point on the w in trulyAwesomeFunction you can mark subwords forward or backward but I don't know a command that would mark Awesome, then extend the region backward, then extend it forward. To do that you could use a sequence like: `M-@ M-b C-x C-x M-f`. That is: mark the word at point; extend the region back one word; jump to the other end of the region; extend the region forward one word.